# Swift - Good way to store paging data with Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, userdefaults

Here is a response for user list returns data with paging data.

```
{
  "user": [],
  "since": 20
}
```

`since` value is used next API call for paging.
I converted user array to `User` realm objects and then store in realm.
But for the `since` value, I have no idea a good way to store it.

I can store it in `UserDefaults`. But I am not sure it is good.
Or I create `UserResponse` realm object class and it has `user` list and since value. But I think it is worse than using `UserDefaults`
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well what do you need it for?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson My app shows cached user list first in case of disconnected network. After networks connected, when scrolling down list, app should call next user list with since value.

Comment: Then can't `since` be calcucated from the number of entries in your cached user list?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes. unfortunatley it cannot be calculated

Comment: I don't know your full use case, but if its just a generic call to get all users couldn't you just use the count of Users in the Realm db? The UserDefaults solution is a simple one to keep you going if needed.